# How to select the cylinder object and not the outer reference surface?

Tags: objects, selection-tools

I am starting out with blender and it is difficult for me to explain in words, I am attaching image for reference:

I want my cylinder object to be selected like this:

[image]

But currently it is selecting the outer reference:

[image]

I added the cylinder in edit mode just as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRikRe054XY). Please let me know where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click the "On cage" icon inside the Subdivision modifier

[image]