# How to keep the original geometry of the preview when using Subdivision surface?

Tags: modeling

I'm working on a model following a time lapse and ran into this problem where the subdivision surface when applied creates more faces than what the time lapse continues with which makes it harder to follow. This is what I end up with when applying the modifier:

[image]

And this is how it should be:
[image]

Im following this time lapse (the modifier is applied at 1:00): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2Qd8CZNF2Q

As you can see it keeps the same geometry from the "optimal display" preview shown when you first add the modifier after you apply it. How???

I've ran out of ideas of what to try and no one else has seemed to have this issue which makes me wonder what am I missing?

Comment: Hello and welcome, when you apply the subdivision modifier, you will get more geometry, you could reduce the level to 1 but it is always going to add more geometry to your object. The second image looks like when you have the modifier but not applied

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! But that's the thing though, When they applied the modifier it stayed like that and they could edit it in edit mode and they continued the time lapse like that.

Comment: The video does not show the action of "apply" so, i can tell you that they did not applied the modifier but they do have "on cage" activated on the modifier so you can see it in that way. https://imgur.com/a/g839d59

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190944/how-to-select-the-cylinder-object-and-not-the-outer-reference-surface/190948#190948

Comment: Oh my god I feel so dumb, thank you! I'm learning to model so I don't really know how modifiers work properly yet, Thanks a ton! This really helped!