# Subdivision surface and mesh

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

When I'm working with **Subdivision surface**, I can't get the mesh I want.
*1img my initial version, 2img that's what I need*.
I solve this problem with UV editor help, but it's long and annoying. In many tutorials the desired mesh appears automatically, but I don't know how to do it :(
[image: initial version]

[image: that's what I need]

Comment: what about just applying your subdivision modifier? but to be honest...i have no idea how you can solve this with the UV editor, because the mesh itself has nothing to do with UV editor....

Comment: what do you mean by "I solve this problem with UV editor help"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select the cylinder object and not the outer reference surface?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190944/how-to-select-the-cylinder-object-and-not-the-outer-reference-surface)

Comment: @Chris
Thanks, this really helped! And do you know how to make it automatically applied when I am using a Subdivision surface?

Comment: go to edit mode -> right click -> subdivide -> in the panel (left bottom) set smooth to 1, choose as many cuts as you want